# Problem with flags?

Tags: discussion, review-page, flagging, 10k-tools

Is there a problem with flags right now?

I have a bunch of flags that I raised that have been waiting for review for a few days now.  They are all fairly obvious "not an answer" ones. Before, they were handled very quickly.

They also keep showing up on the tools/flags page, and in the new review pages.

Or, is this a result of the changes to the review system?

Comment: How strange, I was just about to ask the same thing :) It might just be that the mods have been busy over the last few days and haven't got round to it. Maybe we could do with some new mods to help them out? Not sure how you go about asking for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bam! Handled. :)

I'll be keeping an eye on the flag queue and the site in general for a few days to help with the workload while Kiamlaluno's away.

Answer (score 2):

Kiamlaluno has taken a week off! From his profile:

> I am taking a week break. If you have questions about my answers, use the snail-mail to reach me. ;)

That will probably explain the slow down in flag resolution.

Happy holidays @kiamlaluno :)